# Clean film negatives heavily contaminated with wet paper made negative cases

Tags: film, cleaning, negative-film, negative

I put my film stripes too early in my paper made negative cases. Even more, i put a couple of heavy books on those cases to quickly flatten the film.
The result: the film got stuck - more precisely: sticked to the paper which now is somehow glued on the negatives. How can I safely clean it off?

[image: contaminated film]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Soak in a tray or tube of water at room temperature. Add two teaspoons of Dawn dishwashing detergent per quart (liter). Soak for several hours and test the paper to film adherence. If not free, continue soaking. In time the film will release from the paper. Now wash the film for 10 minutes in running water at room temperature, follow with a 30 second dip in PhotoFlow or equal and hang up to drip dry.

Comment: Since people are a lot less familiar with developing film these days, it's probably a good plan to specify that you don't don't mean full strength PhotoFlow, but an appropriate diluted solution. (Follow the directions on the bottle -- the ratio is something like 1 part PhotoFlow to 200 parts water.)